# Flexbox children does not respect height of parent with flex-direction column

Tags: css, flexbox

The general idea is to have 2 rows of equal heights and the first row contain 2 columns of equal width for a full page layout. The problem I'm running into is that when one of the cells fill up with children elements, the parent row's height expands overtaking the sibling row when the heights should be equal.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  border: dashed 1px;
  flex: 1;
}
.row1 {
  display: flex;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  border: dashed 1px black;
  margin: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.title {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.things {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.things li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">Cell 1</div>
      <ul class="things">
        <li>thing 1</li>
        <li>thing 2</li>
        <li>thing 3</li>
        <li>thing 4</li>
        <li>thign 5</li>
        <li>thing 1</li>
        <li>thing 2</li>
        <li>thing 3</li>
        <li>thing 4</li>
        <li>thign 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row2">Row 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `flex` is a shorthand property, `flex: 1` means

```css
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

But for some reason, the `0%` seems to confuse Chrome. So add `flex-basis: 0` manually:

```css
.row { flex-basis: 0; }
```

And since Firefox implements the new `auto` as the initial value of `min-height`, it needs

```css
.row { min-height: 0; }
```

So the final code is

```css
.row {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  border: dashed 1px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
.row1 {
  display: flex;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 8px;
  border: dashed 1px black;
  margin: 4px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.title {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.things {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.things li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Acct</a>
</header>
<div class="content">
  <div class="row row1">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">Cell 1</div>
      <ul class="things">
        <li>thing 1</li>
        <li>thing 2</li>
        <li>thing 3</li>
        <li>thing 4</li>
        <li>thign 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="title">Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row2">Row 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still usefull after 7 years. Adding `min-height: 0` solved the problem for me in Chrome.

Comment: Still useful after 8 years :pray: